# Creating automatic redirect wiki page 2013 foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, redirect, wiki-pages

I am setting up a wiki in 2013 foundation. 
Since people tend to use different ways of expressing the same, I would like to be able to make imediate redirecting wiki pages.

I've seen several discussions on this platform about problems with the execution, however I found nowher how to actually realise the redirecting in itself for a foundation version.

I would prefer a solution without adding external apps, since my employer does not favour adding these ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So you have empty Wikipages which serve as a stub?

The ductape approach is to place javascript on the page with a Content Editor WebPart

```
<script>
   window.location='[YOURURL]';
</script>
```